# Async VBA Function

Tags: excel, vba, asynchronous

I have a VBA function that is supposed to get some information from the user's cell, make a POST request with that info, then print the response in the output cell.

It's required that the user be able to make about 2000 requests at a time, so I thought to make the requests async to help improve performance.

As it stands right now, I have a function ConnectToAPI that makes the asynchronous request, then passes the response off to a callback function.  The problem I'm having is that the data lives in the callback function, but I need it in the query function in order to return it.

```
Function Query(ID, quote, field)  
  Application.Volatile
  Query = ConnectToAPI(ID)
  Some logic with parsed data from callback
End Function


Function ConnectToAPI(ID)

    Dim Request As New WebRequest
    Dim Client As New WebClient
    Client.BaseUrl = "http://www.endpoint.com"

    Dim Wrapper As New WebAsyncWrapper
    Dim Wrapper.Client = Client
    Dim Body As New Dictionary
    Body.Add "ID", ID
    Set Request.Body = Body
    Request.Method = HttpPost

    ConnectToAPI = Wrapper.ExecuteAsync Request, "CallbackFunction"
End Function

Function CallbackFunction
    Callback = Parsed Data
End function
```

So ultimately in the query function, I want to write

Query = (Parsed Data From the Callback)

How can I pass the data from the callback back up to query?

It is important that the cell have the Query function in it.  The data updates frequently, so we want clients to be able to calculate the workbook to get the newest data.

With what I currently have, my thought process is that the callback will pass the data back to ConnectToAPI, then that will be passed up to Query.  However, my function returns 0 and I think this might be that the parsed data is not available once the function tries to return.

For reference, I am using the VBA-Web library
https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-Web

Comment: Some questions, 1) what is a "Post Request"?  Be specific or provide a link.  2) A lot of what you are talking about here is very unclear, please provide some code and/or examples.

Comment: Are you perhaps talking about a POST request to a web server through HTTP?

Comment: You'll have to establish a global "mapping" of the requests (perhaps including a request "ID" that is returned in the response) that indicates the destination cell for the response.

Comment: We're going to need some of your code to help you here, but if you want asynchronous VBA code, you'll need to use an asynchronous API, and look into class modules, `Event`, `RaiseEvent`, and `WithEvents` keywords.

Comment: Yes @RBarryYoung.  I've edited my question to reflect this.

Comment: Also, if you're on Office 365, asynchronous callbacks is the default - but then you're writing TypeScript, not VBA. Might be worth looking into that.

Comment: Thanks @MathieuGuindon, I'll look into that.  I've also added some code

Comment: You're making a `Function`, but never make it return anything. `foo = MyFunction(args)` is how you pick up the return value at the call site (drop that `Call` statement), and `MyFunction = result` is how you assign the function's return value (inside that function - i.e. by assigning to the function's identifier).

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I tried taking your suggestion (dropping the call and using the function name for returning), but I think the asynchronous nature is preventing the parsed response data from being available at the time the function tries to return it

Comment: I meant that for the `Call ConnectToAPI(ID)` instruction, which should be `ConnectToAPI ID`, and then if `ConnectToAPI` isn't meant to return anything then it can be made a `Sub`; it being a `Function` makes the caller *expect* a return value.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I updated the code to show what I currently have

Comment: Not familiar with the API, but I'm pretty sure `ConnectToAPI = Wrapper.ExecuteAsync` isn't assigning the async result; there's no `Await` keyword in VBA to do this. You need to change your paradigm: the `Query` function cannot use the returned value, since it's not available yet... assuming the `ExecuteAsync` function is truly asynchronous - if it's a blocking call then all is good. Does the API expose any events? Browse its type library (F2) to find out. We need to know if `ExecuteAsync` returns immediately or if it awaits the result - can't answer otherwise.

Comment: @PeterT I tried this approach, but the problem is the destination cell now contains the response value instead of the function =Query(ID, quote, field).  If the user wants to refresh to get the most recent values from our backend, they would have to retype the function and all its parameters.  I think this makes for a poor user experience.

Comment: The callback typically has to do the work, not just parsing the result, but also call all subsequent work/subs/functions. Or else raise an event as Mat's Mug said. Also as Mat's Mug said, no await keyword in VBA, therefore you cant assign like that. I don't know the API, but suspect they are setting onreadystatechange to a default object function call. This may well call Application.Run("CallBackFunction").

Comment: Asynchronous setups are trickier in VBA because you have a little bit more Object/Function design to consider, unlike say a C# situation(where you can use 'await' keyword). They have presumably set up the Wrapper to handle the onreadystatechange, but you need to try and fit the rest of your logic flow in the Callback function. For simplicity, you may need to put the bottom half of your query function in the CallbackFunction, or perhaps yet another function call if desired. See where that leads you...

Comment: ooops I literally didnt see Tinman's dive into the code below...

Comment: @MathieuGuindon someone forked the library to include events that can pass the result of the async call back up the chain.  I am unsure how to implement this though, mainly: how do I get the Query function to listen for the event, and how do I get the query function to wait for the response.  The repo can be found here: https://github.com/Sophist-UK/VBA-Web/blob/WebClientAsync/src/WebClientAsync.cls

Answer (score 3):

[VBA-Web/src/WebAsyncWrapper.cls](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-Web/blob/master/src/WebAsyncWrapper.cls)

[image]

`WebAsyncWrapper.ExecuteAsync` has an optional parameter: `CallbackArgs`.  Use this parameter to pass back you an ID or a cell address.

`ExecuteAsync` has an example callback function that receives an Array of arguments.

[image]

Here is how you can get the information back to the function for processing.

```
Sub ConnectToAPI(ID As Variant, quote As Variant, field As Variant, CellAddress As Variant)

    Dim Request As New WebRequest
    Dim Client As New WebClient
    Client.BaseUrl = "http://www.endpoint.com"

    Dim Wrapper As New WebAsyncWrapper

    Dim Body As New Dictionary

    Body.Add "ID", ID
    Set Request.Body = Body
    Request.Method = HttpPost
    Set Wrapper.Client = Client
    Wrapper.ExecuteAsync Request, "Callback", Array(ID, CellAddress)
End Sub

Public Function Callback(Response As WebResponse, Args As Variant)
    Dim ID As Variant, CellAddress As Variant
    ID = Args(0)
    CellAddress = Args(1)
    With Worksheets("Web Requests")
        .Range(CellAddress).Value = Response
        .Range(CellAddress).Offset(0, 1).Value = ID
    End With
End Function
```

[MSDN - Application.Volatile Method (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/excel-vba/articles/application-volatile-method-excel?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm133230)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

> Marks a user-defined function as volatile. A volatile function must be recalculated whenever calculation occurs in any cells on the worksheet. A nonvolatile function is recalculated only when the input variables change. This method has no effect if it's not inside a user-defined function used to calculate a worksheet cell.

I would not recommend trying to have a UDF that can be used as a worksheet function to return the web-requests.  `Application.Volatile` will cause all 2000 queries to refresh every time a value is changed.  When the first query updates all the other queries will refresh.  This will cause an infinite loop and crash the application.

```
Function Query(ID, quote, field)  
  Application.Volatile
  Query = ConnectToAPI(ID)
  Some logic with parsed data from callback
End Function
```

Using the `Worksheet_Change` event would give the users the ability to update the information without the problems associated with `Application.Volatile`.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Columns("A")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Count = 1 Then
            Debug.Print Target.Value, Target.Address
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks TinMan.  Let me just make sure I follow.  Are you suggesting that I pass in a  cell address, and write the response from the callback to that cell in a separate sheet (Web Requests in your example)?  If I'm correct, I'd be able to use that value in the function, but only if it is available in time from the callback, so I think I'd have the same problem.

As for Application.Volatile, it's a constraint placed on me by my boss.  I agree with you, but she is adamant about having it this way.

Comment: @KWalsh: I second, third and fourth what TinMan says about `Application.Volatile`. In this instance, I would request in writing from your boss the "guidance" that `Application.Volatile` is to be used, and that she will take all responsibility for the performance issues. Seriously - `Application.Volatile` is really bad news - like nitroglycerine, useful in a very small handful of cases otherwise there are many safer and better ways of achieving the result. In addition to the link TinMan provided, look up "Excel Volatile Functions" in your search engine to get a better idea of what this means.

Comment: You will need to pass a unique identifier to the wrapper class to be passed back to the callback function; so you will know how to process the data.

Comment: In my pseudocode `Web Requests` was meant to refer to the same worksheet using the `Worksheet_Change` event.  Because the callback function (which can actually be a `Sub`) needs to be in a public module, it will need to know what worksheet the address belongs to.

Comment: If you absolutely must use an UDF with `Application.Volatile`, you could have the UDF return the value of the Target cell address.  I would initially set the Target cell's value to `Loading...` and in adjacent cells track the status and timestamps of the request.  In this way, you will be able to update the UDF's without triggering requeries.  You will also need a mechanism to continue any queries that did not return a result before the workbook was closed.

Comment: In my answer to [Retrieve data from eBird API and create multi-level hierarchy of locations](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/196922/171419), I have list several articles about making Asynchronous HTTP requests.  I think that the `WinHttpRequest` class used by that library can only do 5 requests at once.  It might interest you to know that using 50 to 100  asynchronous `MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP` requests at a time, I was able to process 3936 requests to 16 seconds.

Comment: @TinMan thanks for the references, will read those articles now.  My problem with the current solution is that the output doesn't follow the format of =Query(id, quote, field).  The idea is that the user would have the output in this format, then can F9 refresh for the latest values.

I see you mentioned the workbook_change event for getting the latest values, but I don't quite follow the logic.  I will spend some time working through this.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up populating a dictionary with the response values from the API call, then recursively calling the query function in the callback.

Query checks if the response value is in the dictionary, if it is, then it returns it.  If not, it connects to the api, the callback puts the value in the dictionary, and also calls the query function again.